# Using libtool to link against non-libtool libraries

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, libtool

I have a project set up with **autotools** to build a C++ library including Python bindings with Boost.Python.
I have a binary of Boost.Python on my system that I want to link against:

```
/usr/lib/libboost_python-py27.so.1.49.0
```

There is no corresponding .la file so I thought I could add the full path to the library to the **libtool** command similar to this:

```
bash ./libtool --mode=link g++ -rpath /usr/local/lib src/o1.lo src/o2.lo ... \
     /usr/lib/libboost_python-py27.so.1.49.0 -o libNSM.la
```

But **libtool** is discarding the **/usr/lib/libboost_python-py27.so.1.49.0** from the issued **g++** command. If I run **g++** by hand it works fine.

How can I make **libtool** use a native shared library or what would be the proper way to handle such a situation. I definitely want users to be able to use their existing boost binaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a binary of Boost.Python on my system that I want to link against

Have you installed `boost-devel` to install the symlink to `/usr/lib/libboost_python-py27.so.1.49.0`?

> There is no corresponding .la file

It's not required for `libtool` to link.  If the `boost-devel` package is installed `-lboost_python-py27` will probably suffice.

> How can I make libtool use a native shared library or what would be the proper way to handle such a situation. I definitely want users to be able to use their existing boost binaries.

You might want to look at the [AX_BOOST_PYTHON](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_boost_python.html) macro from the [GNU Autoconf Archive](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/index.html) 
to help the user set up the desired library for `libboost_python` (You might need more than just that particular macro from there).  The [boost.m4](https://github.com/tsuna/boost.m4) macro also seems to support python, and should provide something similar.

Comment: I'm using AX_BOOST_PYTHON and it gives me the path to the boost library (which in my case is just /usr/lib). But it's not a boost problem, it's a general problem. Let's say I'm using a non-popular library in my project and the users of my software only have a shared library (not a libtool one but just the .so file). How can they build the project if libtool doesn't accept non-libtool libraries? What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: It seems like there is no way to link a library with a non-standard filename with libtool. The library needs to have the file-ending .so or .la.

Comment: The Boost development package (e.g. `boost-dev` or `libboost-python1.49-dev`) should provide a symlink (with a `.so` extension) to the shared lib.

Comment: Again, `libtool` doesn't require a `.la` file to link.  If a `.so` file is a shared library on a platform, `libtool` will link it with the usual linker options `-L`, `-l`.

Comment: Yes you're right. *libtool* needs an *.la* or *.so* file. But giving it a file with another ending doesn't work (even though it might be a shared library and *g++* can handle it). Thanks!